# HADOOP :: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: WordCount

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, classnotfoundexception

I am using eclipse to export the jar file of a map-reduce program. When i am run the jar using command

```
 hadoop jar hadoop-prog.jar WordCount /home/temp/input /home/temp/output
```

it always shows the error :

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: WordCount
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:149)
```

Btw, I get a sample example jar file of wordcount from internet and it ran very well.

I could not figure out where is the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're trying to run the wordcount provided in the examples, you should run:

```
hadoop jar hadoop*examples*.jar wordcount /home/temp/input /home/temp/output
```

More info on how to run wordcount on [this link](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/#running-a-mapreduce-job).

In general, if you're developing your own Map/Reduce jobs, you should include the full package name of your driver class, so something like this might work:

```
hadoop jar wordcount.jar com.something.WordCount /home/temp/input /home/temp/output
```

Comment: My WordCount driver class doesn't have a full package name, it's just a class.