# How I can use map reduce program to check if a value of column match with a criteria?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

How can we use the algorithm Map Reduce to check whether the values of a column in a data file correspond to a given criterion?

e.g: for a column `C1` we want to check that the values of this column match with the criterion : `C1 in ("A", "B", "C")`.

My desired output is to save in a table all the identifiers of lines which meet with my criterion, and in the other tables the others who don't match. my current code is :

```
public class SmallDataMap extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text> {`

    @Override
    protected void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        String[] tokens = value.toString().split(",");
        if (tokens.length != 8) {
            return;
        }
        String gds = tokens[6];
        if (gds.equals("AMA") || (gds.equals("ABA"))) {
            context.write(new Text(gds), new Text(tokens[0]));
        }

    }
}
```

The code of the main class is :

```
public class SmallData {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        String[] ourArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "Structuration par code gds");

        job.setJarByClass(SmallData.class);
        job.setMapperClass(SmallDataMap.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(ourArgs[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(ourArgs[1]));

        job.waitForCompletion(true);
    }
}
```

I generate the jar file and when I tried to execute my job in Cloudera, I have this error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class smalldata.SmallDataMap not found
```

Comment: How is your input stored in HDFS? What is the current code that you have and it's not working? Why is it not working? What is the desired output? Probably the downvotes are due to a lack of such information

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Go through the basics of MapReduce first, in order to understand how it works. It's not an algorithm, it's a programming model that you can use to write your own algorithms. I recommend [this tutorial](https://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/index.html) for start.

After that, regarding your question, you don't need a reducer for that. A map-only job should suffice. You can just apply your criteria in the mapper and emit the records that meet your criteria.

The pseudocode for the mapper is as simple as:

```
map (LongWritable inputKey, Text inputValue){ //assuming value is stored as Text
    String[] columns = inputValue.get().split(",");
    if (columns.length != 8) return; //or throw IllegalArgumentException
    C1 = columns[6];
    if (C1.equals("A") || C1.equals("B") || C1.equals("C")) {
        emit (inputKey, inputValue); //assuming that you just need to keep the records which meet your criteria
    }
}
```

For more details you can read some MapReduce Design Patterns (there is also a [book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920025122.do) with that title that contains examples of filtering criteria like the one you describe).

Comment: in my case, I have a csv file, wich contains 8 columns separated by comma (","), and I would verify if a column number 7 in (A,B,C).

Comment: in my case, I have a csv file, wich contains 8 columns separated by comma (","), and I would verify if a column number 7 in (A,B,C). how I can apply your answer in this case ? I didn't undrstand this line in your code : `C1=inputValue.extract(c1)`  .Also, what will be the input value if I would save all id of lines where c1 match to my criterion, in a table, and other table that contain the other ids of lines who don't match

Comment: It means, extract the 7th column of your line (e.g. by splitting the String represeting the line by the "," delimiter)! The input value will be a single line each time and the input key the line number. That's why I suggested that you read some MapReduce basics first.

Comment: @Cleo see my updated answer. Also, some things to consider, to improve the question and thus, the quality of the answers: How is your input stored in HDFS? What is the current code that you have and its not working? What is the desired output?

Comment: I updated my question, the input file is a CSV file stored in HDFS. I use Cloudera CDH5.4.0

Comment: @Cleo however, this, now is a completely different question. Maybe this post can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14554088/hadoop-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-wordcount

Comment: They aren't the same issues, I launch my job in Cloudera and I didn't understand why it doesn't find my map class :/