# Word Count Program in Hadoop Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, hadoop

I am using eclipse to export the jar file of a map-reduce program. When i am run the jar using command:

`hadoop jar Mapreduce.jar Mapreduce siva/file1.txt`

Then Show Errors in

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Mapreduce
enter code here
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:201)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:200)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:325)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:270)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:149)
```

I could not figure out where is the problem.Please help me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14554088/hadoop-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-wordcount

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HADOOP :: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: WordCount](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14554088/hadoop-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-wordcount)

Answer (score 0):

you need to give full class name.I mean package name also
For example if my class name is Mapreduce and package name is com.hadoop.ex
then your command should be
hadoop jar MapReduce.jar com.hadoop.ex.MapReduce inputFile outputfile